# Удалить кавычки и квадратные скобки оставив только теги. Python

Tags: python, строки, list

Вывод программы выглядит так:

```
["<img src='https://telegra.ph['/file/------.jpg']>", "<img src='https://telegra.ph['/file/------.jpg']>", "<img src='https://telegra.ph['/file/------.jpg']>"]
```

Нужно убрать квадратные скобки, кавычки и запятые

Вывожу в консоль это подобным образом, возможно тут тоже надо внести изменения:

```
for photo in photos:
    photo_link = upload_file(f'{dir_name}/{photo}')
    uploaded_photos.append(photo_link)


    img = []
    for tag in uploaded_photos:
        img.append(f"<img src='https://telegra.ph{tag}>")
```

Comment: Вы хотите удалить все цифры в списке строк `img`? Поэтому написали `img = str(img)`, `print(re.sub('[\d]', '', img))`? Если нет, то, скорее всего вам нужно `img.append(f"<img src='https://telegra.ph{tag[0]}>")`. Кажется, `tag` - это список, а не строка.

Comment: Нет, извиняюсь, ошибся при копировании. Цифры обязательны.

Comment: Тогда ваш вопрос не имеет отношения к регулярным выражениям, я удалил тег.

Comment: Добавьте в код как именно вы выводите результат, и что у вас в uploaded_photos. Также есть подозрение, что не должно быть отступа начиная со строки `img = []`.